# EditText's drop down number pad shows "next." How to force "Done?"

Tags: java, android

I have a Fragment (a tab) with an EditText, a Spinner and two NumberPickers, in that order.
When the user "clicks" on the EditText the number pad drops down. But it does not show "Done." Instead it shows "Next" and although the Number picker is covered, the next number entered goes to the **second** NumberPicker.

(In C++ windows I could have controlled the Z order. Not sure why the first NumberPicker is skipped.)

The default in the NumberPickers is usually what the user will want. How can I force the number pad to show Done after the one and only EditText widget has been satisfied?

The form is not vertically scrollable.

Comment: Curious why this was voted down. 
I could understand if the number pad progressed through all of the widgets that can accept a number, but not why it would choose the first and the last. All four are numeric. 
My actual question "how to force" is surely a valid question.

Comment: I've edited the title so the question doesn't appear to be **quite** so stupid.

Comment: "Next" took me to the third widget because the second is a Spinner and IME does not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `imeOption` property of `EditText`. set its value to `actionDone`

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. User now has the option of scrolling "Picker" or entering a number in the other widgets.

Comment: Just one note. I was using an OnKeyListener on the EditText (this is code I wrote early on when I knew even less than now).  With the IME changed to "Done" the Listener's onKey never fired. I have changed it to an OnEditorActionListener and it works fine.

Comment: One last problem? If the user types some digits but dismisses the soft keyboard using the down arrow ( "V"), then the number has not been processed. How to detect that the soft keyboard has been hidden?